# Minikube not starting on Ubuntu 20.04 (cri-docker.socket)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I can't seem to start minikube on a VM with Ubuntu 20.04.
I've tried running `minikube start` but it threw

```
VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM)
```

Then I tried running `minikube start --driver=none` and it threw the error

```
Exiting due to RUNTIME_ENABLE: sudo systemctl enable cri-docker.socket: exit status 1
stdout:

stderr:
Failed to enable unit: Unit file cri-docker.socket does not exist.
```

Does anyone know what is the correct way to create a Kubernetes cluster on a Ubuntu VM? I'm connected to that VM through SSH (if that makes any difference).

Comment: You need to also install cri-dockerd. I suppose 1.24 is version you are using.

Comment: Well now throws another error - `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`